# Converting long dates in python. Wed Sep 07 10:35:00 IST 2022 trying to convert this into python. with help of strptime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

```py
def date_convert(date_to_convert):
     return dt.datetime.strptime(date_to_convert, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

data['Publish Time'].apply(date_convert)
```

when running this it says

> "" ValueError: time data 'Wed Sep 07 10:35:00 IST 2022' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y' ""

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to replicate the issue you're facing with the exact same code you've provided.

```py
import datetime as dt

def date_convert(date_to_convert: str) -> str:
    return (dt.datetime.strptime(
                date_to_convert,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y').
            strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))

date_convert('Wed Sep 07 10:35:00 IST 2022')  # 09/07/2022
```

However, you can also accomplish the task using the builtin `dateutil` library.

```py
import dateutil

def date_convert(date_to_convert: str) -> str:
    return dateutil.parser.parse(date_to_convert).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

date_convert('Wed Sep 07 10:35:00 IST 2022')  # 09/07/2022
```

Comment: Will this method also applied to a column as well?

Comment: You can apply it to a Pandas DF column sure. It's just like any other method in Python

Comment: When applying to column it gives C:\Users\vikas.raj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py:1201: UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname IST identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
  warnings.warn("tzname {tzname} identified but not understood.  "
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Defence')

Comment: This might just happen to be working on *your* system if your local time zone is IST. %Z does not parse arbitrary tz abbreviations (in fact most parsers won't - abbreviations are ambitious!). To use dateutil correctly here, you'll have to define a `tzinfos` dictionary (mapping tz abbreviations to IANA tz names).

Comment: @FObersteiner I was unaware of it being locale dependent. Noted

Comment: @AbirbhavG. it's also platform-dependend, do make it even worse ;-) oh and I meant "tz abbreviations are ambiguous", not ambitious. I love auto-correction ^^

Comment: btw. here's an example of how to use the tzinfos dict: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69673614/10197418